# How to update base relative URL in angularapp?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have an existing angular app which routes/imports (eg: `href` and `src`) from the root path only (ie: `/`). So the app loads up at `http://localhost:8080/` and and the base url is `/`. I want to change it to be `http://localhost:8080/myapp/` so all links will then prefixed with /myapp.

I tried updating this code here from (it's in a Java jsp called app.jps):

```
<head>
    <base href="/" />
```

to

```
<head>
    <base href="/myapp" />
```

But this did nothing, I still get errors like this (and others like it): `angular.js:11630 GET http://localhost:8080/angularapp/home/home.html?version=4 404 ()`

There are many other errors like this, and the page is just blank (white) so far. Do I have to go and piecemeal edit all these urls to include `/myapp` in front of it? **OR is there a better way?**

More info:

Template Urls look like this (in app.module.js):

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/angularapp/home/home.html?version=' + window.version,
            controller: 'HomeCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
```

Comment: have you stopped your ng serve and restarted it? when you change files that are outside the app folder I think it requires you to quit ng serve and start it again.

Comment: Not running it through ng serve. It's being built into a war file and tomcat embedded is running it. I added a context path `/myapp` and it now won't work unless I go and piecemeal edit all the changes.

Comment: could you post more code and info about setup? does home.html exist? should it be index.html instead? or just /home?

Comment: you could also try using absolute paths in your components to the templates

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing the end slash.

```
<head>
<base href="/myapp/" />
```

Please update href to "/myapp/", that should work.

Comment: Yeah it's still broke. Im' getting 404's because angular is making ajax requests to links like this `http://localhost:8080/angularapp/home/home.html?version=11` instead of `http://localhost:8080/myapp/angularapp/home/home.html?version=11`

Answer (score 0):

If you change your `templateUrl` to:

```
templateUrl: './angularapp/home/home.html?version=' + window.version,
```

it should take it as a relative path.
Try that and see what it gives you (assuming your base url already comes off `http://localhost:8080/myapp/`).

Comment: Yeah I had to do that for every templateUrl. I am so new to angular so I thought there was a better way but this was the only way I knew so I went with it.

Comment: To future-proof it, and since you have to do it anyway, try changing it to 
`templateUrl: rootUrl + '/angularapp/home/home.html?version=' + window.version,` and set a global variable of `rootUrl ` set to "." (or whatever your site's root url is). That way if it changes in the future you only have to do it in one place